# SAML 2.0 implementation returns 403 after logged in

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta, spring-saml

I implemented a saml security configuration with okta and it is returning 403 after the user logged in from the okta page when he goes to /saml/sso url. I guess the service does not accept the answer returned from OKTA but why? Here is the securityConfig.xml.

Seems like the samlWebSSOProcessingFilter does not authorize the incoming request although the user is logged in successfully. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>


    <!-- Unsecured pages -->
    <!--
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/>
    -->

    <!-- Security for the administration UI -->
    <!--<security:http pattern="/saml/web/**" use-expressions="false">
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/saml/web/metadata/login"/>
        <security:form-login login-processing-url="/saml/web/login" login-page="/saml/web/metadata/login" default-target-url="/saml/web/metadata"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/metadata/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    </security:http> -->

    <!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
    <security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="false">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
        <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    </security:http>

    <!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
            <!--<security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFiler"/> -->
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
    </bean>
    <!--
    Use the following for interpreting RelayState coming from unsolicited response as redirect URL:
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler">
       <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
    </bean>
    -->

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
    <bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/"/>
    </bean>


    <!-- Handler for successful logout -->
    <bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
    </bean>


    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
        <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
        <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI --> 
        <!--security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
                <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider-->
    </security:authentication-manager> 

    <!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
    <bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

    <bean id="keyResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
        <constructor-arg>
                        <value type="java.io.File">/home/karinca/softwares/oktaxmlserver/saml/keystore.jks</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
    <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg>
                        <ref bean="keyResource"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="secret"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="spring" value="secret"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="spring"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
    <bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
        <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
                <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
    <bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
        <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/idpSelection.jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
    <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
                <property name="extendedMetadata">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
    <bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

    <!-- Configure HTTP Client to accept certificates from the keystore for HTTPS verification -->
    <!--
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer">
        <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
    </bean>
    -->

    <!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
    <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
               <!-- <property name="defaultIDP" value="https://dev-08103053.okta.com/"/> -->
    <property name="defaultIDP" value="http://www.okta.com/exk1i88ayj5jwcuH85d7"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <!-- Example of file system metadata without Extended Metadata -->
                <!--
                <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value type="java.io.File">/usr/local/metadata/idp.xml</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
                -->
        <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value type="java.io.File">/home/karinca/softwares/oktaxmlserver/saml/metadata/sso.xml</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains information about this service provider -->
        <!-- <property name="hostedSPName" value=""/> -->
        <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used for authenticating user by default. -->
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
        <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->
        <!--
        <property name="userDetails" ref="bean" />
        -->
    </bean>

    <!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
    <bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
    <bean id="logoutHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
        <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
      <!-- URL containing the metadata -->
      <constructor-arg>
        <!-- This URL should look something like this: https://${yourOktaDomain}/app/abc0defghijK1lmN23o4/sso/saml/metadata -->
        <value type="java.lang.String">https://dev-08103053.okta.com/app/exk1i88ayj5jwcuH85d7/sso/saml/metadata</value>
      </constructor-arg>
      <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
      <constructor-arg>
        <value type="int">5000</value>
      </constructor-arg>
      <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
    <!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
    <bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
                <ref bean="postBinding"/>
                <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
                <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
                <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
    <bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
    <bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
    <bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="processor">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                        <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

    <!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

    <!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
    <bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize">
        <property name="builderFeatures">
            <map>
                <entry key="http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion" value="false"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: 403 error after. theuser logs in from the IdP indicates that the certificate being used is probably not correctly set on the application. That's one of the scenarios where I have seen similar issue.